# Where to place database in codename one

Tags: codenameone

Please where can I place my database in codename one? by default, is under .cn1 then database folder. In my own case I want to pack my database with my apps, I am now confused where to place it. I have information that I must access inside the database. I placed it on src directory but I can not access it. Guide me here. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Place your db file under the src/ folder of your app and try this:

```
Database myDataBase = com.codename1.db.Database.openOrCreate(DB_NAME);

if(Storage.getInstance().readObject("initalized") == null){
    myDataBase.close();

    String path = com.codename1.db.Database.getDatabasePath(DB_NAME);            
    OutputStream o = FileSystemStorage.getInstance().openOutputStream(path);
    InputStream i = Display.getInstance().getResourceAsStream(getClass(), "/" + DB_NAME);
    Util.copy(i, o);
    Util.cleanup(o);
    Util.cleanup(i);

    myDataBase = com.codename1.db.Database.openOrCreate(DB_NAME);
    Storage.getInstance().writeObject("initalized", "true");
}
```